# How download a image from database?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

i´m trying doing download of url image, but it´s not working, is the next, I have a app where the user profile can upload image, and it´s ok on the emulator, but if i swith emulator i dont have image. :(

```
             String image = dataSnapshot.child("images").getValue().toString();
             if(!image.equals("")){
                //Glide.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).into(image_profile);
                Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_add).into(image_profile, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_add).into(image_profile);

                    }
                });
            }
```

Image of realtime Database getting url of image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hnng.png)

Please help me guys!
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image link ends with the image format such as JPEG or PNG and etcetera.
Put your link in the load() method such as

> Glide.with(this@thisActivity).load("image url").into(imageViewID).